# How to start Celery Beat on Flask

Tags: python, flask, cron, celery, celerybeat

I currently have a flask code that looks like this 
**app.py**

```
from services.celery_maker import make_celery
from flask import Flask
from datetime import timedelta

template_dir = os.path.abspath('./build/')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir, static_folder=os.path.abspath("./build/static"))

app.config['ERROR_404_HELP'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = config.get("DEFAULT", "SECRET_KEY")
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(minutes=5)

app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0',
)

app.config['CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE'] = {
    # Executes every minute
    'periodic_task-every-minute': {
        'task': 'periodic_task',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30)
    }
}



@app.route('/')
def view():
    return "Hello, Flask is up and running!"

@celery.task(name ="periodic_task")
def periodic_task():
    print('Hi! from periodic_task')
    logger.info("Hello! from periodic task")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

I have my celery maker in a different file to stop relative import errors

**services.celery_maker.py**

```
from celery import Celery


def make_celery(app_name=__name__):
    backend = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
    broker = backend.replace("0", "1")

    return Celery(app_name, backend=backend, broker=broker)


celery = make_celery()
```

celery worker sees my task but it doesnt run at all I don't know what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the periodic tasks in celery, you need to use celery beat also, beats will schedule the tasks and workers will execute the task, in short along with the worker you need to start the celery-beat also

```
celery beat -A <path_to_worker_created_under_celery_app> -l info
```

for eg. in your case`celery beat -A services.celery_maker.celery -l info`